# Webdriver (wd) tests work locally but time out on Travis CI?

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, mocha.js

I have some tests written with gulp-mocha-selenium which uses wd under the hood. It may be important to note it is the 'wd' driver not vanilla Webdriver.

tests are here:
https://github.com/UWFosterIT/react-starter/blob/master/test/acceptance/hello-spec.js

My travis.yml is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10.37"
before_install:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - "npm install -g eslint gulp eslint-plugin-react webpack"
before_script:
  - "sleep 30"
script:
  - "gulp check"
  - "gulp test:server"
  - "gulp test:acceptance"
addons:
  firefox: "31"
```

The tests work fine locally, but time out on TravisCI.org. I'm not sure where to start looking.

Travis results: https://travis-ci.org/UWFosterIT/react-starter/builds/55222925

Comment: My timeouts are as high as 30s but it's still timing out. I must be missing something.

Comment: I've got Firefox working locally if I start a standalone selenium server. It works on Mac and Ubuntu. So I'm just stumped why it's not working on TravisCI :-(

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to download and start Selenium on TravisCI

```
before_script:
  - "wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar"
  - "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar > /dev/null &"
  - sleep 3
```